# How to set two homepages, one for Mobile version and the 2nd for desktop version?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have made two homepages and i want to set the 1st for the desktop version and the 2nd in the mobile version. I'm using wordpress.

Comment: Are you wanting completely different homepages (styles and content)?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, server-side, client-side, style-oriented, user-agent sniffing, etc.  We cannot answer broad "how to" questions without more context.

Comment: If you are talking about 2 completely different templates, then you would need to detect the browser / os and serve your template based on it - in the past we have used this for the detection: https://51degrees.com/, but nowadays it's just easier to make responsive templates instead as they are easier to maintain as you're not updating 2 templates every time there is a change

Answer (score 1):

If what you wanna see it's diferent styles but with the same html, what you can do it's use the `@media` selector on CSS that gonna let you choose styles for mobile or desktop